# Read in a .plist

Tags: iphone, plist

I want to read in my .plist but my NSLog is equal to "(null)".
Here is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"data.plist"];

NSLog(@"%@", [plistDict objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

And here is my .plist: http://cl.ly/image/2e3P3Q1z2Z1T

Answer (score 2):

Your path is wrong. If your plist is in your app resources, then you have to use [`NSBundle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get it's absolute path.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] 
                              mutableCopy];
```

If it's in your app's documents folder, you can do this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *path = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
```

Note that a dictionary or array loaded from a plist is always immutable. You have to create a mutable copy.

Comment: My plist is in _~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/iOS/Applications/MY-APP/Documents_ but this code doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6907432/343340) on how to get the documents folder path. And see my updated answer.

Comment: NSLog is equal to "(null)" again...

But my code looks great:

`- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, SUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *path = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data-article-itiap.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"id"]);
}`

Comment: Either there is no key `id` in your dict. Or the file doesn't exist. Log `path` and see if the file is really at that location.

Comment: I really don't understand, my code is great and I got the key "id" (string) in my dictionary. Maybe it's bugging because my root is an array?

Comment: Of course that's the problem. You should have said that earlier. See [my answer to your other post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13113756/343340).