# Strange bug with plist

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, plist, title

I got a very strange bug when I'm trying to read my plist.
My plist looks like :

```
Root (Array)
            Item 0 (Dictionary)
                              title (String)
```

I want to display `title` in the log, so I did the code bellow:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *path = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"title"]);

NSLog(@"Path to plist: %@", path);
```

With this code, `NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"title"]);` is equal to "`(null)`"...

My plist is in my app's documents folder, and the log of `path` return the good path to my plist.

Help me please :)

Comment: One, this is not a strange bug, this is not having read the documentation. Two, the problem is inherently unrelated to Xcode, since it would be the same if you used Eclipse or vi to write your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your plist is an array but you read it into a dictionary, thats won't work.

You should:

- read the plist into an array
- get item 0 (objectAtIndex:0) -> this is a dictionary
- on this dictionary you can perform objectForKey ...

Comment: Thank you guys, it's working fine :) !!

Final code:

    `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *path = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data-article-itiap.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *dict = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
    
    NSMutableDictionary *dicto = [dict objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [dicto objectForKey:@"category"]);`

Comment: Hint : when your question is answered, you should accept an answer as the solution. If you don't you won't get help in the future ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Tom said, (and as you said yourself in your first code block) the root of the plist is an array.

You can load an array very similarly using:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Then you can access the item at index 0 (the dictionary) like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or since Xcode 4.4 with thew new array literals:

```
NSDictionary *dict = array[0];
```

And then log the title as you already tried:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"title"]);
```

Or with the new syntax:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"title"]);
```