# FTPHelper library not working iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp

Hello I have this code and don't download anything...

```
    FTPHelper *ftp;
    ftp.urlString = @"ftp.marignal.com";
    ftp.uname = @"whttpapp.marignal.com";
    ftp.pword = @"hidden";
    ftp.filePath = @"Barcos/Imagenes";
    [ftp download:@"catlanza.bmp"];
```

I'm using this lib: https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper

That method download, It suppose to install the selected file in Documents directory...

Comment: `ftp.filePath = @"Barcos/Imagenes";` Does this directory exist?

Comment: Yes I have checked it right now and exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the simulator for the path it copied to.

Likely you need to tack on Documents:
ftp.filePath = @"Documents/Barcos/Imagenes";

Or get the path programmatically:
[What is the documents directory (NSDocumentDirectory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory)

Comment: Look in the other folders before "Documents" in the simulator folders to see where it actually went.
/Users/[YOUR USERNAME]/Library/Application Support/iPhone simulator/....