# Images Stored in NSUSer Default

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

i have an 4 imageview in that if click on 1st imageview image transfer to next drawable view here user can edit the image using drawpad. user can draw line or rect on that image i want to save that image to NSUserDefault and when user back the first screen replace that original image with previous selected image

Save image to NSUserDefault i used this code.

```
-(IBAction)SaveBtn:(UIBUttonSender*)sender
{
    [delegate.imagesDef setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(previewImageView.image) forKey:@"first"];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"first"];
                 delegate.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    NSLog(@"%@",[delegate.image description]);
    NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
    [delegate.imagesDef synchronize];
}
```

This code works fine image save. i log it but when i goes previous controller image not replaced

i used this code for set new edited image.

```
if([delegate.imagesDef objectForKey:@"first"])
    {

        NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"first"];
        delegate.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        NSLog(@"%@",[delegate.image description]);
        NSLog(@"%@",imageData);

        NSLog(@"%@",delegate.image);

        FirstImageView.image=delegate.image;    
    }
```

image not changed how may i solve this.

Please help me out this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use core data or sqlite database, because userdeafaults is used for store small variables not that big type of values.

Comment: You would rather store the link to the image (in a database or NSUserDefaults, depends on 1. how many and 2. is it really a user default setting?) and save the image as a file.

Answer (score 5):

You should not store an `UIImage` into the `NSUserDefaults`. `NSUserDefaults` is meant for small pieces of data but not a whole image.
Just write the image to disk (into the documents directory) and save the path into NSUserDefaults.

**Loading:**

```
NSString *pathToFile;
UIImage *image;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pathToFile forKey:@"image"];
```

**Restoring:**

```
NSString *pathToFile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

But why aren't you just passing the UIImage object itself between your ViewControllers using properties?

Comment: But beware that the full path to Documents changes with each update of the app (there is a random-generated component in the app directory's path). Better to save the path relative to Documents.

Comment: But you can always get the path to you documents directory. And the content there stays the same.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory

Answer (score 0):

First of all using `NSUserDefault` for this thing is not recommended.

**Few alternatives :**

1) you can assign this image to `firstViewControllers` property so that you could access it later if you have its object declared in `secondViewController`

2) You can send a `NSNotification` to firstViewController thought which you can send the image to `firstViewController` from `secondViewController`

**Hope this will help you.**