# How to keep old data while updating new iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My iOS app is using `NSCoreData` and stores lots of data in the database. I designed the database schema in `*.xcdatamodeld` file in xcode. I am planning to update my application soon and need to change the schema a little. However, when I tested it, new version is removing all old data, saved in previous version.

How can I effectively migrate to new database schema without loosing old data in the app?
I tried to google for a suitable solution, but could not find any effective idea, how to do it.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what extent you're changing your schema. If they are minor changes, an automatic migration will take care of it - you just need to add another model version number. If they are significant changes, then you'll need to write a manual migration

Comment: Hi, The changes are minor. I needed to add some extra attributes in an entity. Could you please point me any reference, how to set version number in my model?

Comment: Then you just need to do an automatic migration. Search for it as it's pretty easy to implement in your code. Also a quick google search for "xCode model number" points you to the Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH8-SW1 and https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/setting_current_version.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH9-SW1

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful. One small question though. If my already published app doesn't have any model version number, is it going to work if I assign a version number in the new one?

Comment: It should. But honestly this question is answered extremely quickly for you - install the app from the app store, then run it off xCode with the new model number on a device. You can see what happens for yourself. If it doesn't work, then you can research on how to fix it.

Comment: What about NSCoreData?

Answer (score 0):

Use **documents directory** it will keep your data even if you update the app.

you can find out about documents directory here [What is the documents directory (NSDocumentDirectory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory)