# XCode 7 - fstream does not work in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ifstream, ofstream

the below shown functions are working well in Xcode, as long as I use them in OSX-applications...
now I wrote an iOS-application where I would like to save some data in .txt files and read them again, but it does not work... there are neither files written, nor read...
I already searched the net for solutions but I only found solutions to whenever it does not work in the OSX application (wrong directory, etc...) but that is not my case, there I already got it working...

what is the difference when I use it in the iOS simulator and how to get it running there?

//the below code is now the corrected version (before it was posted without the "this was missing" part.

```
void SaveData(std::string FileName)
{
    //!!this was missing
        char *H = getenv("HOME");
        std::string Home(H);
        std::string FileName = Home + "/Documents/" + FileName;

    std::ofstream FileOut (FileName);

    if (FileOut.is_open())
    {
        //!!write data to file
        FileOut.close();
    }
}


void LoadData(std::string FileName)
{
    //!!this was missing
        char *H = getenv("HOME");
        std::string Home(H);
        std::string FileName = Home + "/Documents/" + FileName;

    std::ifstream FileIn;
    FileIn.open(FileName.c_str(), std::ios::in);

    if(not FileIn.good())
    {
        //!!error message
        return;
    }

    //!!read data from file
    FileIn.close();
}
```

Comment: What does "encryption process is needed for each line before writing to file" mean? Data does not have "lines", it is just  bytes. Lines are an application level concept.

Comment: What is the file path, add that to the question. iOS restricts the area that can be read and written to.

Comment: "encryption process" is just a comment for me that I need to insert the data conversion functions later on, as soon as the initial test are done.
its irrelevant for now (just a comment), I forgot to delete that before posting (I stripped down the code to the relevant lines only so it is more readable for you guys).

the file path is "users/me/documents/xcodeprojects" thus the user defined path where I store my xcode projects...
I expected something like this to be the problem, but I do not find any infos on the net where it should be (iOS vs OSX), how to set it up (or even where to set it up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS is Sandboxed and restricts the area that can be read and written to and `users/me/documents/xcodeprojects` is incorrect.

See [About the iOS File System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12) for details.

There are several directories you can write and the Documents directory is probably what you want. You have to make a call to get the path, here are example calls in C++, Objective-C and Swift:

C++ (Thx: Moritz Buchty):

```
char *H = getenv("HOME");
std::string Home(H);
std::string FileName = Home + "/Documents/" + FileName;
```

ObjC:

```
NSArray *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
```

Swift:

```
let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
```

Comment: that c++ syntax sounds promising as with that I don't even have to read the directory out somewhere in my ObjC user Interface and route it down, I can read it directly in the c++ core program where I need it.

Comment: it worked...
with a small adjustment...
the constant char "/Docs" could not be appended to the char *home, a constructor was required in-between...
I inserted the new code in my example above with "this was missing"

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file to your application's `Documents` folder. For more information about it, read [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6907381)

Comment: thanks, now it all starts to make sense...
I was googling for several weeks now but probably was using misleading keywords... it drove me nuts...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28