# Storing data through app updates in App Store/Google Play with React-Native AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

Considering that I have an application in the App Store/Google Play, which will locally save some data in AsyncStorage (React-Native) depending on the user interaction, what will happen with that data if I make an updated version of the app and push it to the App Store/Google Play?

It will still be saved in AsyncStorage?

Answer (score 1):

if you are saving data in your document directory then after updation it will still remain as same. you can overwrite or use save same data. you can also make new directory for new version data also.

Comment: Could you expand a little on that, please? I'm new to mobile development :)
What you mean by: 'document directory', where exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory