# Saving base64 string as .pdf in mobile local storage flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, base64, decode

This is the path " /data/user/0/com.example.flutter_pdf_proj/app_flutter/example.pdf" i am getting while converting base64 string to bytes using path provider package.

[image]

I can open the PDF and view in mobile.

now i a have to save this PDF in mobile local storage in mobile. How can i do that.

Please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is already saved, otherwise how could you "open" a file that is not yet "saved" on the device?

Comment: i cannot find the file in device. I searched everywhere. Can i save it in custom folder path in local storage?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423058/cannot-find-the-path-provided-by-getapplicationdocumentsdirectory

Comment: i tried it but getting this issue "Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0//example.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i donot have filemanager in my emulator. So i am unable to view the downloaded path in the device. So now i have installed file manager in my emulator device and able to see the PDF docs in the device. So thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can let users to locate where they want to save their pdf (or any files you generate before) using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_dialog. It can help you in "duplicating" file to specific folder as they want to.