# How to Store the image in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

facing with one problem,How to store images in NSUserDefaults that image contains url like this (www.example.com/1.png),how to store that images help me please.
Here is my code,

```
listBannerArray =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

imageArray = [listBannerArray valueForKey:@"mainbanner"];
NSLog(@"%@",imageArray);

NSUserDefaults *imageDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [imageDefaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"kPrefKeyForMainBanner"];
        NSLog(@"image :%@",[imageDefaults objectForKey:@"kPrefKeyForMainBanner"]);
```

Here listBannerArray is my total response and imageArray is my images array. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Why don't you save that image in Directory??

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:key]; here what is image?

Comment: Are you work in Objective C or Swift?

Comment: ok...Let me check it

Comment: Have you get array of images?

Comment: yes images are stored in my imageArray but that is in the format of url

Comment: you just should not store bulk data in `NSUserDefaults`; the `Documents` folder is your friend here.

Comment: give mi some code @holex

Comment: @MangiReddy, why? where have you been stuck during the implementation?

Comment: @holex i am getting images into imageArray,but that will be a url? how can i hit that url and save that image into userdefaults

Comment: @MangiReddy, you _do not_ want to save any bulk data into the `NSUserDefaults`; for fetching an image via http:// scheme you can use `NSURLSession`.

Answer (score 3):

To save an image in NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:key];

To retrieve an image from NSUserDefaults:

NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read how to do such thing [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults), but again - **it's not the best practice** to do.

For correct approach, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934852/how-do-i-save-and-read-an-image-to-my-temp-folder-when-quitting-and-loading-my-a?rq=1), for example.

Answer (score 0):

**You can store and  retrieve an image from NSUserDefaults like this:**

**NOTE:-**

**1.If you have UIImage object then you need to use UIImagePNGRepresentation to store .png image.**

**2.For .jpg/.jpeg UIImageJPEGRepresentation( lossy compression)if you use a compressionQuality value smaller than 1.0, you can lose some image quality.**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

To retrieve an image from NSUserDefaults you can get it from NSData:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"]; 
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```